# How to make domain point to a folder in application (Windows2008 server)

Tags: windows

I have a VPS WIN2008 server. I am pointing multiple domains to one server. I want all the requests from all the domains to be handled by one web application. 
The question is how can I make each domain point to different folder in my web application?

Answer (score 1):

The following link will point you in the correct direction.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28WS.10%29.aspx